# Splitting a polynomial into sum of factors, not necessarily linear

Tags: polynomials, factorization

How can I split a given polynomial as sum of factors in Mathematica?

For example, let's say I have this polynomial: $2\cdot x^2+7\cdot x+2$.

I would like the output to be $(x+1)(x+2)+x(x+4)$. Is there a way to do that with Mathematica?

Comment: What you want is not really factorization, because that's about *multiplication* of factors. There's an infinity of terms that can be *added* to arrive at the same result. But have a look at [`Factor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html?q=Factor) anyway.

Comment: 'Factor' doesn't give a possible way to write factors as sum of products.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = 2 x^2 + 7 x + 2;

expr2 = (x + a) (x + b) + x (x + c);

expr2 /. Solve[Equal @@ (CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ {expr, expr2}),
   {a, b, c}, Integers][[-1]]
```

> (1 + x) (2 + x) + x (4 + x)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, is it possible to implement such a procedure symbolically and for any given polynomial not necessarily quadratic?

Comment: I believe not. The target form (expr2) would have to be specified and generally not all polynomials of a given order can be expressed in the specified form (even if just quadratic).